# Android app crash but show no error from Logcat

Tags: android

I created one recyclerView. I want that, when it is scrolled to final items, it will load more item to list.

When I commented code in line `list_more_res.addAll(tmp_more);` app is not crashing but when I deleted comment in above line, then app started to crash, but it shows nothing in logcat. Can someone help me with this?

```
    reference.child("restaurants").limitToFirst(200).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        RestaurantEntity res = child.getValue(RestaurantEntity.class);
                        rest_List.add(res);
                    }

                    //start
                    list_more_res = rest_List.subList(0, 20 > rest_List.size() ? rest_List.size() : 20);

                    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                            = new LinearLayoutManager(HomeActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

                    hot_categories = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.prd_categories_hot);
                    hot_categories.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    productList = new ArrayList<>();
                    res_hot_adapter = new RestaurentAdapter(HomeActivity.this, list_more_res);
                    hot_categories.setAdapter(res_hot_adapter);
                    hot_categories.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(layoutManager) {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {

                            tmp_more=  rest_List.subList(20*count_loadmore ,20+ 20*count_loadmore>rest_List.size()? rest_List.size() : 20 + 20*count_loadmore);
                            int curentSize = res_hot_adapter.getItemCount();
                            list_more_res.addAll(tmp_more);
                            /*res_hot_adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(curentSize, res_hot_adapter.getItemCount()-1);*/
                            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,tmp_more.size()+" more",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            count_loadmore++;
                        }
                    });

                   /* hot_categories.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(HomeActivity.this,
                            new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                                    Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, RestaurentDetailActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                }
                            }));*/
                    // end load from firebase
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Reconnect ur device!!

Comment: use a Debugger to find out if `list_more_res` is null or not!

Comment: I tried using debugger , list_more_res is not null

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do :

```
list_more_res = rest_List.subList(0, 20 > rest_List.size()-1 ?     rest_List.size() : 20);
```

Comment: I think that is  not reason because when I run Log.d(TAG,list_more_size+") is result =20 from logcat.

Comment: Yes it will show 20 ..  but 20 is count and sublist(0,19) parameter should like this.

Comment: I know this but it not reason app crash because when hot_categories.addOnScrollListener not run recyclerview is worked and you see my adapter res_hot_adapter = new RestaurentAdapter(HomeActivity.this, list_more_res); if list_more_res error I thinks recyclerView will not show.